# Display & Video 360 No permission for attempted operation on PARTNER with ID

Tags: google-api, google-api-php-client, dv360

We have implemented Google API for Display & Video 360 in Google PHP API client.
When we execute the API it returns the below error response:

```
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "No permission for attempted operation on PARTNER with ID \"******\".",
"status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
}
}
```

We have verified the partner ID in the DV 360 console and API keys in the Google Cloud console. Any leads on how to fix this would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: did you get the solution. ? If yes please try sharing the same as i am also facing the same.